# Treat missing data as just another category

Tags: classification, graphlab, sframe

I have some data which is mostly user demographics. There are lot of survey questions which people have answered "yes" or "no". But the data naturally contains lots of missing values. I don't want to impute the missing values. I want to treat that as a third category. So each question has three possible answers - "Yes", "No" and "NotSure".

What I am doing till now is :

```
model = graphlab.boosted_trees_classifier.create(train,
validation_set=None, target = target, max_iterations = 80, verbose = False)
```

where `target` is what I am predicting (It is binary 1 or -1). Now both my `train` and `test` dataset has lot of missing values so for that what I was doing till now is:

```
predictions = model.predict(test, missing_value_action='impute')
```

But these predictions are not giving me good accuracy. I want to convert each two category answer *(Yes/No)* to three category *(Yes/No/NotSure)*. How to go about doing that?

I tried :

```
colNames = train.column_names()
for i in colNames[6:]:
    train.fillna(i,'NotSure')
```

This executes without any error but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry are you asking how to do `df.fillna('NotSure')`?

Comment: @EdChum Something like that but for multiple columns and graphlab's syntax for doing that.

Comment: You have to assign back to the column or pass param `inplace =True`

Comment: but it doesn't supports `inplace` argument :(

Comment: Oh thanks! Got it `train=train.fillna(i,'NotSure')` :)

Comment: semantically it should be `train[i] = train[i].fillna('NotSure')` also I think `train[colNames] = train[colNames'].fillna('NotSure')` should work